# XPath. Get text inside tags not followed by additional text outside the tag

Tags: r, xpath

I have two patterns in html page the only difference between them is an existance of aditional text after the closed **strong** tag. Here is an example:

Sample 1 (with additional text after the tag **strong**):

```
<p><strong>14h45 De violents combats ont lieu à Zawiyah</strong>, à 40km à l'Ouest de Tripoli entre les insurgés et les forces restées fidèles au colonel Kadhafi. Un témoin oculaire, cité par l'agence de presse italienne Ansa, affirme: "C'est un massacre, il est difficile d'estimer le nombre de morts". Il y aurait une centaine de victimes, selon la BBC. &nbsp;</p>
```

Sample 2 (without additional text):

```
<p><strong>Quitte à revenir dans l'euro quelques années plus tard?</strong>&nbsp;</p>
```

I need two XPath so I can get text inside tags '<*strong*>...<*/strong*>' for both cases.

Right now I m using

```
'//p//strong//text()[normalize-space()]'
```

but it captures text from both samples while I need two separate XPaths.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPD**
Also is there a way to handle cases when

```
<p>
    <a href="http://www.slate.com/id/2286172/" target="_blank">
        <strong>Combien coûte un mercenaire?</strong>
    </a>
    Alors que le régime de Kadhafi semble avoir recours à des combattants étrangers pour réprimer les insurgés, Slate se penche sur leur fonctionnement... et leur émoluement (en anglais).&nbsp;
</p>
```

The XPath

```
"//p//strong[not(following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()])]//text()"
```

will return:

```
Combien coûte un mercenaire?
```

However there is a text after the  tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use `following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]` in predicate for `strong` to get only `strong` elements that is followed by non-empty text nodes :

```
//p/strong[following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]]/text()
```

and use the opposite predicate `not(following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()])` to get the rest of the `strong` elements :

```
//p/strong[not(following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()])]/text()
```

Notes: the above will work assuming that `&nbsp;` is considered a white-space in the XPath library that you're using. Otherwise, you might need to compare the length of the text node following the `strong` element with the length of the text `&nbsp;`, to determine if the text node is more than just a white space (`&nbsp;`), something like :

```
following-sibling::text()[string-length(normalize-space())>string-length('&nbsp;')]
```

Comment: Thank you, @har07, that works good. Could you please also check UPD in my question.

Comment: AFAIK, that can't be done using only XPath 1.0 expression. What about returning the `p` tag using XPath and then get the text content from `r`, if possible..